# linq to entities nested select fillout

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to return a result and a nested result in a linq to entities query.

```
Orders[] orderlist =
(from m in db.Orders.Include("OrderLines")
    where
    areas.Contains(m.Area)
    && m.Branch == branch
    && (m.OrderStatus == "1" || m.OrderStatus == "4")
    && m.SpecialInstrs == string.Empty
    select m
HOW??---> m.OrderLines = m.OrderLines.Where(p => (p.LineType == "1" || p.LineType == "7") && p.MBomFlag != "C").ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

The problem is that the include returns all the FK'd OrderLines for each order when I really only want certain order lines.

How do I do this?

Orders and OrderList are both POCO entities generated by L2E and the poco entity generator.

Comment: Is OrderLines not available on the Orders entity as a NavigationProperty that you could be checking against?

Comment: it is, but the question I'm asking here is basically 'include' brings all the orderlines.  I only want the orderlines that have linetype==1 etc.

Comment: You might think about giving this a go if it makes sense: [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/190229/438306.aspx) or try splitting up the call into two methods one for getting the Orders and one for getting your OrderLines based on the retrieved Orders.

Comment: it already works fine if I split it up into two calls.  I'm trying to learn some LINQ here to see if this can be done in one call.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually join them:

```
Orders[] orderlist = (from m in db.Orders
                      join p in db.Orderlines
                        on p.OrderId = m.Id
                      where areas.Contains(m.Area) 
                        && m.Branch == branch
                        && (m.OrderStatus == "1" || m.OrderStatus == "4")
                        && m.SpecialInstrs == string.Empty
                        && (p.LineType == "1" || p.LineType == "7")
                        && p.MBomFlag != "C"
                      select m).ToArray();
```